# Injective module equivalent form

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $e$ be the idempotent element of finite dimension algebra $A$, how to prove that all left injective $A$-module has the form $D(eA)$, where $D = Hom_k(-,k)$ is the dual functor. I know that $eA$ is projective, then by duality, $D(eA)$ is injective. But I can't prove the inverse argument.

Comment: Are you sure you have the statement correct? The dimension of $D(eA)$ is at most the dimension of $A$, but there are plenty of injective modules with larger dimension. Maybe you mean *indecomposable* injective modules?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is finite dimensional, direct sums of injectives are again injective, and every module has a non-zero socle.

If $X$ is semisimple, then we can write is a direct sum $\bigoplus_jS_j$ of simples $S_i=e_i(A/J(A))=\mathrm{soc}\,D(Ae_i)$, where $J(A)$ is the Jacobson radical. Thus $X$ is the socle of the injective module $E(X)=\bigoplus_jD(Ae_j)$.

In general, every module $X$ embeds into the injective module $E(\mathrm{soc}\,X)$. In particular, every injective $I$ is a direct summand $E(\mathrm{soc}\,I)$, and since they have the same socle, they are equal. This shows that every injective is a direct sum of such $D(Ae)$.